# bootstrap-datetimepicker show date only

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I am using this [repo](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker) by smalot and I want to select and show date only (for some other places I am showing data and time, therefore selecting this repo). I can manage to use it for selecting date only but the generated date string is always `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii`. And if I did not understand wrongly the `format` option is for parsing the initial date only but not setting dates.

```
<div class="input-group date datetime dateonly" data-start-view="2" data-min-view="2" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Release Date" id="release-date" name="release_date" value="{{ unit.release_dt|date:'Y-m-d' }}" style="cursor: default; background-color: #ffffff;">
    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
</div>
```

I am setting `startView` and `minView` to be both `2` so that the user will need to select date only but I still got `2015-09-22 00:00` as the output-- I just want it to show `2015-09-22`.

In fact, by listening to `changeDate` and hide events, I can just set the value of date inputs. I am wondering if there is a less hacky and dirty way of doing it

```
$('.datetimepicker').on('changeDate', function(e) {//get substring and set date input
}).on('hide'....//same thing
);
```

Comment: The format will remain for dates user will select, not only for setting initial dates..

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Specify format for date like, `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});` Also, can you create fiddle for it to investigate?

Comment: Sadly to say this but the library is on my computer and I do not have any idea which version it is using(existing code).

Answer (score 5):

Use date picker

```
$("#calender").datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
});
```

Comment: Better to describe your answer.

Comment: using data-format(in mark up) does not give me any request

Answer (score 5):

To show date only use

```
format: 'L'
```

To show Time only use

```
format: 'LT'
```

Reference

```
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/832
```

Answer (score 0):

you will edit datetaimepicker.js

```
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    autoclose: false,
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    //format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', 时间输出格式
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'en',
    minViewMode: 0,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    weekStart: 0
};
```

like this

```
    //format: 'mm/dd/yyyy', 时间输出格式
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

wish can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
HTML:

```
<div class="controls input-append date m" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-field="m1" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-start-view="2" data-min-view="2">
<input size="16" id="m" type="text" value="" readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="m1" value="" />
```

JS:

```
$('.m').on('changeDate', function(e) {
            console.log($("#m").val());
        });
```

Console:

```
2015-12-08
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I am not using this one... whether you are talking about https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ or https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I have edited my answer. Please do check.

Comment: the key is data-date-format? I changed that but it is not working

Comment: Yes, you are right. data-date-format is supposed to be set. Check the value of input having id as "release-date" you are getting after selecting date.