# Bootstrap Datepicker shows Time in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-datepicker

I use bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0 in My Razor Pages Projekt (.Net Core 2.2).

Datepicker Configuration:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        language: '@currentCulture',
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "bottom left",
    });
```

HTML Template:

```
<input asp-for="ViewModel.DateTimeProperty" data-provide="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
```

The current language is DE (German). After having selected a date, the format of the displayed date is correct: **14.06.1989**.
Then I save the data set with the changed DateTime property. The page reloads. Now, the displayed format is: **14.06.1989 00:00:00**
How can I prevent the input field to show the time part of the DateTime property?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check this question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525664/bootstrap-datetimepicker-show-date-only/34526014

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Veljko89. The suggested answers in the mentioned question do not work for me :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For first showing before choosing the date, you could control it by configure `DataType` like below on the entity.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! I'm now using the attributes like this:         [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DateTimeProperty { get; set; }